# Node JS npm install through command prompt is giving warnings

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have been following codelab instructions to implement Real-time communication with WebRTC and while trying to run npm-install I am getting the following warnings.

npm WARN webrtc-codelab@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN webrtc-codelab@0.0.1 No license field.

audited 52 packages in 0.81s
found 16 vulnerabilities (11 low, 1 moderate, 3 high, 1 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Can someone help me with fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

The first ones are because of the licence and repository fields of the package.json being empty, you can fill them using docs for [licence](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#license) and [repository](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#repository).

The latter ones are due to outdated dependencies used by the code sample, it is ok to ignore this warning for an educational project because the vulnerabilities often are not important if you are not planning to use the project on a production server. But if it is bothering you you can use `npm audit fix` as suggested by npm, it'll try to update dependencies if there are no breaking changes in the upgrade it might not succeed in doing so for some or all of those packages in which case you'll need to manually install the newer version of those packages but beware cause doing so COULD break the code sample to the point that it'll no longer work.